# After slicing or filtering a pandas dataframe, f_regression behaves not as expected

Tags: python, pandas, regression

Really don't understand what's going on. I'm checking the f_regression p-value of a variable against itself.

```
seg = data_with_clusters
print seg.shape, f_regression(seg['ALSFRS_slope'], seg['ALSFRS_slope'])[1]
```

As expected, this gives `(2366, 16) [ 0.]` = 0% chances that the regression parameter is zero. 
But after I filter or simply slice it:

```
seg = data_with_clusters[data_with_clusters['cluster'] == 0]
print seg.shape, f_regression(seg['ALSFRS_slope'], seg['ALSFRS_slope'])[1]
seg = data_with_clusters[:1000]
print seg.shape, f_regression(seg['ALSFRS_slope'], seg['ALSFRS_slope'])[1]
```

It gives this:

```
(2109, 16) [ 1.]
(1000, 16) [ 1.]
```

As in: 100% chance that the independent variable is purely random with respect to itself!!!

Please, what am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: can you post the descriptive statistics of your dataset? say `data_with_clusters.describe()`

Comment: @JianxunLi - sure, here you go: https://github.com/ihadanny/p4l/blob/master/ipython-notebooks/feature_selector_beta.ipynb